# Error: Lorg/koin/android/ext/android/AndroidKoinScopeExtKt

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin, android-koin

```
**implementation 'io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.4.0'**



class SplashActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

private val viewModel: SplashViewModel by viewModel()

...

class MyApplication: Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startKoin {
        androidLogger(Level.ERROR)
        androidContext(this@MyApplication)
        androidFileProperties()
        koin.loadModules(getAllModules())
    }
}
...

 val presentationModules = module {
    viewModel {
        SplashViewModel(
            urlUseCase = get(),
        )
    }
}

val mapperModules = module {
    single(named(urlResponseToUrlAddress)){
        UrlResponseToUrlAddress()
    }
}

...

object AppComponent {

fun getAllModules(): List<Module> = listOf(*getAppModules())

private fun getAppModules(): Array<Module>{
    return arrayOf(
        domainModules,
        mapperModules,
        dataModules,
        otherModules,
        presentationModules,
    )
   }
}
```

ERROR:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/koin/android/ext/android/AndroidKoinScopeExtKt;

I'm trying to implement KOIN in my app.
But I always get this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an issue with the Koin library; make sure you have added the koin for android dependency: `implementation 'io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.4.0', or try cleaning and rebuilding your project, lot of issues are solved like that!

Comment: same error,... same problems